# Отследить запуск другого процесса c#

Tags: c#, .net, процесс

Можно ли как-то отследить запуск другого процесса(cmd.exe) средствами C#? Может быть есть какие-то библиотеки для работы с системными событиями?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так как [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435508/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/482879#482879) для которого я написал данный ответ оказался "дубликатом", выкладываю решение здесь, тем более просили решение на C#, а принятый ответ на VB.

```
using System;
using System.Management; // =>Project => Add Reference => System.Managemen

namespace ProcessMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
            startWatch.EventArrived += startWatch_EventArrived;
            startWatch.Start();
            ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
            stopWatch.EventArrived += stopWatch_EventArrived;
            stopWatch.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            startWatch.Stop();
            stopWatch.Stop();
        }

        static void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process stopped: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
        }

        static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Для отслеживания конкретного процесса можно записать так:

```
ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
                new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace WHERE ProcessName = \"notepad.exe\""));
```

**Важно!** Использование [ManagementEventWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) требует привилегий администратора.

Возможные параметры которые можно использовать в представленном WQL запросе можно посмотреть [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394374(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Хм.. Какой-то другой способ. А в чём разница по сравнению с моим?

Comment: @Qwertiy по сути никакой, просто ваш на VB, а этот на C#. Когда писал ответ, был не в курсе, про ваш вариант :)

Comment: Нет, они разные - у тебя даже источники другие в запросе: `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` и `Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, а у меня что-то c `__InstanceOperationEvent `. В чём разница между подходами?

Comment: @Qwertiy присмотрелся, таки разница есть :)

Comment: @Qwertiy честно говоря я в тупике: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394649(v=vs.85).aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394374(v=vs.85).aspx  описание методов наталкивает меня на мысль, что это разные названия одного и того же.

Comment: Ну у тебя получается два подписчика, которые слушают только то, что им надо, а у меня один, который слушает не только что мне надо, но и что-то лишнее. Впрочем, при sql'ном синтаксисе можно события перечислить в запросе, чтоб лишние не приходили? Что-то ещё интересное?

Comment: @Qwertiy  да можно отслеживать по конкретному имени процесса, добавил в ответ. В прочем по твоему варианту тоже можно отслеживать конкретное имя, однако в моем случае, по всей видимости есть более интересные возможности, например сделать отслеживание по родительскому процессу.

Comment: "Использование ManagementEventWatcher требует привилегий администратора." А если таковых не предвидится?

Comment: @3per тогда вам придется пользоваться костылями. Например путем периодического запроса списка процессов и выслеживания появления нужного вам.

Answer (score 10):

Можно при помощи WMI. Но именно отследить, что он произошёл, а не вмешаться перед запуском, выполнив какие-то действия, и не отменить его.

Вот код на VB.NET (писал давно):

```vb
Imports System.Management

Module All

WithEvents Watcher As New ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA ""Win32_Process""")

Public Sub Main()
  Watcher.Start()
  Console.ReadKey()
  Watcher.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Watcher_EventArrived(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArrivedEventArgs) Handles Watcher.EventArrived
  Dim EventType As String = E.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName
  'Dim Prc As New Win32_Process(TryCast(E.NewEvent("TargetInstance"), ManagementBaseObject))
  Dim Cmd As String = TryCast(E.NewEvent("TargetInstance"), ManagementBaseObject)("CommandLine")

  Select Case EventType
    Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
      Console.WriteLine("{0:-16} {1}", EventType, Cmd)
    Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent"
      Console.WriteLine("{0:-16} {1}", EventType, Cmd)
    Case "__InstanceModificationEvent"
      'Console.WriteLine(EventType)
  End Select
 End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: "Можно при помощи WMI. Но именно отследить, что он произошёл" Именно это мне и надо, спасибо большое :)

Comment: _"при помощи WMI. Но именно отследить, ... не отменить его"_  -- есть метод [Terminate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa393907(v=vs.85).aspx) его можно вызвать после события __InstanceCreationEvent.

Comment: @Stack, естественно, прервать процесс можно (да хоть через Process.Kill по id), но это именно прерывание, а не отмена запуска.

Comment: @Qwertiy в описании Terminate сказано "Preventing a process from running in the first place." -- preventing = предотвращение. по идее - отмена. хотя в msdn может быть ошибка.

Comment: @Stack, "from running", но не "from starting". На момент получения уведомления процесс уже запущен и на время обработки не приостанавливается. Я это вроде тогда ещё проверял. Или `Terminate` можно как-то в сам запрос загнать?

Comment: @Qwertiy понятно. Terminate вызывал из обработчика. как помню, процесс не запускался. наверное он запускался, но ненадолго, окно программы не успевало открыться.